# How to mix "well" and "button" together in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My question is,I want to make the "well" and "button" of same size.
Here is my Html code:

```
<div class="well well-sm" id="well-color">
    <button class="btn btn-default ">More Details</button>
  </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.well{
    margin-right:800px;
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o782w.jpg)
    Could anyone help me on this

Comment: What if you just use a button? Is there a reason behind using well but not showing it extending around the button?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<div class="well well-sm" id="well-color">
   <button class="btn btn-default well">More Details</button>
</div>
```

use space after 1 class and write another class name and it will work .